# Python MySQLdb select fresh data from a infinite thread

Tags: python, multithreading, mysql-python

Using python2.7 and MySQLdb I'd like to have an infinite thread that will perform a SELECT query from times to times. It seems that the only first SELECT is taken into consideration, when I'm modyfing the data in my table in order to have more or less result those ones never change.

Here's my method :

```
def getUrlsToCrawl(self):
    dateNowUtc = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    cursor = self.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT id, url, nbErrors FROM mytable WHERE nbErrors < %s AND domain = %s and nextCrawl < %s', (self.MAX_RETRY, self.domain, dateNowUtc))
    print cursor._last_executed
    urls = cursor.fetchall()
    print urls
    cursor.close()
    return urls
```

The connection to the database is made at the __init__ and the closing when I kill my thread.

And here's the log

```
SELECT id, url, nbErrors FROM mytable WHERE nbErrors < 10 AND domain = 'foo.com' and nextCrawl < '2017-01-04T16:33:52'
((6L, u'http://www.foo.com/foo.php', 4L),)

SELECT id, url, nbErrors FROM mytable WHERE nbErrors < 10 AND domain = 'foo.com' and nextCrawl < '2017-01-04T16:33:59'
((6L, u'http://www.foo.com/foo.php', 4L),)

SELECT id, url, nbErrors FROM mytable WHERE nbErrors < 10 AND domain = 'foo.com' and nextCrawl < '2017-01-04T16:34:06'
((6L, u''http://www.foo.com/foo.php'', 4L),)

SELECT id, url, nbErrors FROM mytable WHERE nbErrors < 10 AND domain = 'foo.com' and nextCrawl < '2017-01-04T16:34:13'
((6L, u''http://www.foo.com/foo.php'', 4L),)
```

If I change nbErrors from 4 to 12 for this entry the result stay the same but the query shouldn't get this result.

I tried to open my cursor at the __init__ and not to close it didn't help. Any suggestion?

Comment: what does it show when you print it ?

Comment: when I print the cursor ? `<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x7f32deef1950>` the memory is changing every call

Comment: no , I mean : `print urls`

Comment: It is already in the main question. I think it might be a cache issue, I tried `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`  but same behavior

Comment: I think the problem is with your query

Comment: try this : `cursor.execute('SELECT id, url, nbErrors FROM mytable WHERE nbErrors < %s AND domain = %s and STRCMP(nextCrawl, %s) = -1', (self.MAX_RETRY, self.domain, dateNowUtc))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem my adding self.db.commit() after cursor.fetchall()

Thanks !